# NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME when connecting to router samba share

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba, smb, smbclient

I have a asus router that I am using to host a samba share networked hard drive. I've been able to connect to this shared disk from both my windows machine and my macbook, so I know the drive "works" in the strictest sense. However I am unable to connect to my share using any of my linux machines.

I am able to run the share list command using smbclient. Here is the output from that.

```
andymc@media-server:/tmp$ smbclient -L //RT-AC86U-CF00/
Password for [WORKGROUP\andymc]:

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    andy (at Elements) Disk      Elements's andy in WD Elements 2620
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (RT-AC86U)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

The andy share that I have setup is clearly visible in the output there.

However when i try to actually connect to that share I get a `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME` error.

```
andymc@media-server:/tmp$ smbclient //RT-AC86U-CF00/andy
Password for [WORKGROUP\andymc]:
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

I'm using an asus `RT-AC86U` running merlin firmware version `386.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The share name that your router actually publishes isn't `andy`, it's `andy (at Elements)`.

Use `smbclient "//RT-AC86U-CF00/andy (at Elements)"` to access it.